# How to customize BotFramework webchat react UI

Tags: reactjs, botframework, web-chat

I'm just started exploring botframework webchat with React. I have tried to come until below UI.

[current ui image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P8DGz.png)

In docs, its mentioned like we can control each parts of the UI using React. But I couldn't see samples that could modify webchat message styles like (user/bot message height, customize message input field). In the ReactWebChat component, there is a className prop.

```
<ReactWebChat 
    className={`${className || ''} web-chat`}
```

Is it recommended to use this classname in-conjunction with message class selector (.web-chat .webchat__bubble__content p) to customize UI ?

[user image inspect element](https://i.stack.imgur.com/89jcU.png)

Thanks

Comment: Was the answer sufficient or do you need more help/info?

Comment: With createStyleSet(), i could able to customize few cosmetic changes. As said by Steven Kanberg, if there's a change in versions, it will definitely break existing code which is based on selectors. I just want to know, is there any persistent class/id selectors which doesn't break on version upgrades Or is there any stable versions of js which i can use for customizations?

Comment: If you use createstyleset, you will be good for future releases. Thats why its there

Comment: Thanks Hessel. As suggested, will use createstyleset.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[This document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/bot-builder-webchat-customization?view=azure-bot-service-4.0) should get you started. Most basic styling is available via configuration-settings.

The border of a textmessage for instance could be implemented via styleoptions:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
    <script src="https://cdn.botframework.com/botframework-webchat/latest/webchat.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <div style="height: 60%; width: 40%; margin-top:5%; margin-left:10%" id="webchat" role="main"></div>
  <script>
     // Set the CSS rules.
     const styleSet = window.WebChat.createStyleSet({
         ...
         bubbleBorderColor: '#E6E6E6',
         bubbleBorderRadius: 2,
         bubbleBorderStyle: 'solid',
         bubbleBorderWidth: 1,
         ...
      });

    window.WebChat.renderWebChat({
      directLine: window.WebChat.createDirectLine({
          token: '<Your Direct Line token>'}),
      styleSet
    }, document.getElementById('webchat'));
    
  </script>
</body>
```

Comment: Hi Hessel, some of the customizations are not there in the documentation. In my case, i wanted to customize border around text message.

Comment: There is a lot of settings wrt the bubble in https://github.com/microsoft/BotFramework-WebChat/blob/main/packages/api/src/defaultStyleOptions.ts

Comment: For clarity, if there is a UI element you want to customize the style of and it is not managed via `styleOptions` or `createStyleSet()` in Web Chat, then you will need to change the CSS directly. Be aware that relying on elements defined by Web Chat classes/Ids are subject to change/removal. This could lead to breaking changes in your code when upgrading to subsequent versions. Sometimes the class or Id is the only element marker, so it becomes a necessary evil to accomplish your goal.

Answer (score 0):

[BotFramework-WebChat](https://github.com/microsoft/BotFramework-WebChat) has a list of StyleOptions that you can override located here:

https://github.com/microsoft/BotFramework-WebChat/blob/main/packages/api/src/defaultStyleOptions.ts

It's possible to use WebChat's `activityMiddleware` to render your own custom message bubbles component:

```
const activityMiddleware = () => (next: any) => (...args) => {
    const [card] = args;
    if (card.activity) {
        if (condition) {
            return (
                <div key={card.activity.id} className='custom-class'>
                    {next(card)(children)}
                </div>
            )
        }
    }
}

... 

return (
    <ReactWebChat
        activityMiddleware={activityMiddleware}
        directLine={adapter}
        styleOptions={styleOptions}
    />
);
```