# Azure bot UI customization in a react website

Tags: reactjs, azure, user-interface, chatbot, azure-bot-service

I am making an azure qna maker bot and embedding it in a react website using iframe. I want to make changes to the UI of the bot, colors, font, size, etc. And add a button to the corner of a website to pop up the chat for the bot. I have attempted to make changes using the bot framework sdk.

https://github.com/microsoft/BotFramework-WebChat/tree/main/samples/01.getting-started/a.full-bundle

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/bot-builder-webchat-customization?view=azure-bot-service-4.0

I am still confused as to how or where I have to add the code changes to the **index.html** file. I even downloaded the bot source code and still do not understand where to make the code changes. I have searched extensively for any other tutorials or videos but found nothing fruitful.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to customize BotFramework webchat react UI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71005239/how-to-customize-botframework-webchat-react-ui)

Comment: [BotFramework-WebChat index.html](https://github.com/microsoft/BotFramework-WebChat/blob/7e27ab3c32055a4b3984b28c2938caec0ac14805/samples/05.custom-components/d.reaction-buttons/index.html)

Answer (score 0):

Check this repro [link](https://github.com/microsoft/BotFramework-WebChat) for implementation.

To check the styles implementation and repro to the own, navigate to

***tests* -> setup -> web -> index.html**

The major styling things shouldn't be modified or mentioned in HTML page. Check the index.CSS and other CSS pages for reference and create your own CSS and map that to **index.html** using **style tag**